# Occupy content space based on the screen size in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have a structure which consists:

an image horizontally stacked with a text array which are vertically stacked like this:
[image]

Here is the snippet for the same:

```
import React from "react";

export default function BoxHeader(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: `${props.Gap}rem` }}>
      <div className="Image-wrapper">
        <img
          className="Profile-Image-Decorator"
          alt=""
          src="https://i.redd.it/rm6sqwpmesb41.jpg"
        ></img>
      </div>
      <div className="Collapsible-Navbar">
        {props.Msg.map((element) => (
          <div className="Message-Holder">{element}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I want to achieve is on reducing the screensize, the text should move below the image, but what I actually get is this:
[image]

By using Bootstrap classes I managed to make a responsive navbar... but I wanted the same with my this section as well. Does anyone have any suggestions for the same?

**For reproducing goto this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-fast-ctyr3?file=/src/components/ImageHeader.js)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Row` and `Col` components to create [responsive grids](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#responsive-grids).

```js
...
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function BoxHeader(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: `${props.Gap}rem` }}>
      <div className="Body-wrapper">
        <Row>
          <Col sm={12} md={6}>
            <div className="Image-wrapper">
              <img
                className="Profile-Image-Decorator"
                alt=""
                src="https://i.redd.it/rm6sqwpmesb41.jpg"
              ></img>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={12} md={6}>
            <div className="Collapsible-Navbar">
              {props.Msg.map((element) => (
                <div className="Message-Holder">{element}</div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-stonebraker-s22fx]